# A more formal alternative for "go with" in the context of food or literature

Tags: single-word-requests, verbs, synonyms, formality

... or the literature on food.

I need a verb for associating things that go particularly well together. Possibly with a wine or French lineage. It is not *pairing*. Other ideas thrown out are *go with* and *complement*, but I think that there should be a more sophisticated word.

Comment: synergetic - working together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider "marry" [from French](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=marry) "[marier](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/marier)."

[marry](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/marry): to unite closely or agreeably; blend.

E.g.

> This wine and cheese marry well.
>
> Seafood marries with other flavors.
>
> [Thai Peanut Sauce Marries Well With Shrimp and Pinapple...](http://www.nytimes.com/2014/03/11/dining/thai-peanut-sauce-marries-well-with-shrimp-and-pineapple.html?_r=0)

Comment: thx, marry is a good word and has a nice literary quality of human marriage

Answer (score 1):

Noun: **accompaniment**

> -2. something that is supplementary to or complements something else, typically food. "sugar snap peas make a delicious accompaniment for
>   salmon"

Verb: **accompany**
[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/accompany)
*A delicious sauce accompanied the grilled fish*

**complement**
[M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/complement?show=0&t=1398034027)
*a delicious dinner complemented by a splendid dessert*

Comment: Oops! Forgot that "complement" had been discarded by the OP, but it is a formal expression, derived from 15th C. Old French *complement* and Latin  *complementum*, so pretty sophisticated if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of a single word but you can use the saying;

- This term goes *hand in hand * with .. Or
- *closely associated with*